# Uploading a img/file to Quickbloxx Custom Objects API?

Tags: javascript, quickblox, postman, custom-object

I'm working on QuickBloxx platform and had a use case where , I need to use some custom data models,I created a custom/class with one text and one file/img as datamodel fields.

I thoroughly followed the following url/documentation[link to quickbloxx custom objects files uploads](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Files):

For debug purpose I'm using Post to initiate POST request to Quickbloxx API as follows:

https://api.quickblox.com/data/coupon/file.json?token=mytoken , "coupon", was my object name.I'm able to POST text content to "customer_name" attribute but I cannot POST image to cust_img  attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiarize with this guide:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Getting_started

*{"errors":{"base":["Required session does not exist"]}}* - need to create a session to avoid this error